# Bootstrap 3 collapsed navbar toggle won't work any

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, navbar

I am currently working on a website with Bootstrap. I've made a custom navbar which is slightly styled with CSS. Since I've added CSS to my navbar it didn't wanted to open anymore when collapsed. I've been searching the whole day in my code, but couldn't found the problem. When I inspect element the navbar and click on the button to toggle, the class changes from **navbar-toggle** to **navbar-toggle collapsed**, so it is doing something, but isn't showing it on the screen.

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Bree+Serif');
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway');

body{
 background: #f3f3f3;

}

.customfont{
    font-family: 'Bree Serif', serif; 
}

.bold{
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #999;
}

div.target{
 display: block;
 height: auto;
 border-radius: 6.666px;
 background: #ffffff;
}

.progress {
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    border-radius: 5px;

}

.progress-value {
    font-family: arial-black;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    color: black;
 
}

p.afstand {
    line-height: 50%;
}

a{
 /*color: #FFFFFF;*/
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}

/*a:hover{
 color: #FFFFFF;
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}*/

.coin-plus {
    color: #1be061;
}

.coin-dip {
    color: crimson;
}

.hover-coin-link:hover {
    color: #1be061;
}

.progress-complete {
    color: white;
}

.progress-bar {
    background: #1be061;
    width: 100%;
    padding:15px 0;
}

.arial-black {
    font-family: 'arial-black';
}

.font-weight-800 {
    font-weight: 800;
}

.small-usd {
    color: grey;
}

.secondary-color {
    color: #053d66;
}

.progress {
    height: 30px !important;
}

.grey-background {
    background: #f3f3f3;
}

.white-background {
    background: white !important;
}

.nav-main {
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

.nav-main a {
    color: #356e98
}

.toggle.btn[data-toggle='toggle'] {
    float: right !important;
    margin-left: 10px
}

@media (min-width: 1500px) {
  .container {
    width: 1075px;
  }
}
.navbar .navbar-toggle .icon-bar {
    background-color: black;
    
}

@media (max-width: 1300px) {
    .navbar-header {
        float: none;
    }
    .navbar-left,.navbar-right {
        float: none !important;
    }
    .navbar-toggle {
        display: block;
    }
    .navbar-collapse {
        border-top: 1px solid transparent;
        box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.1);
    }
    .navbar-fixed-top {
        top: 0;
        border-width: 0 0 1px;
    }
    .navbar-collapse.collapse {
        display: none!important;
    }
    .navbar-nav {
        float: none!important;
        margin-top: 7.5px;

        max-height: 300px;
        overflow-y: scroll!important;
    }
    .navbar-nav>li {
        float: none;
    }
    .navbar-nav>li>a {
        padding-top: 10px;
        padding-bottom: 10px;
    }
    .collapse.in{
        display:block !important;
    }
    .navbar-logo {
        padding-bottom: 20px;
    }
    .navbar-items {
        display: none;
    }
}


.panel-login {
    border-color: #ccc;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 2px 3px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 2px 3px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    box-shadow: 0px 2px 3px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}
.panel-login>.panel-heading {
    color: #00415d;
    background-color: #fff;
    border-color: #fff;
    text-align:center;
}
.panel-login>.panel-heading a{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #666;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 15px;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.1s linear;
    -moz-transition: all 0.1s linear;
    transition: all 0.1s linear;
}
.panel-login>.panel-heading a.active{
    color: #029f5b;
    font-size: 18px;
}
.panel-login>.panel-heading hr{
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    clear: both;
    border: 0;
    height: 1px;
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(left,rgba(0, 0, 0, 0),rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15),rgba(0, 0, 0, 0));
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(left,rgba(0,0,0,0),rgba(0,0,0,0.15),rgba(0,0,0,0));
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(left,rgba(0,0,0,0),rgba(0,0,0,0.15),rgba(0,0,0,0));
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(left,rgba(0,0,0,0),rgba(0,0,0,0.15),rgba(0,0,0,0));
}
.panel-login input[type="text"],.panel-login input[type="email"],.panel-login input[type="password"] {
    height: 45px;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    font-size: 16px;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.1s linear;
    -moz-transition: all 0.1s linear;
    transition: all 0.1s linear;
}
.panel-login input:hover,
.panel-login input:focus {
    outline:none;
    -webkit-box-shadow: none;
    -moz-box-shadow: none;
    box-shadow: none;
    border-color: #ccc;
}
.btn-login {
    background-color: #59B2E0;
    outline: none;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 14px;
    height: auto;
    font-weight: normal;
    padding: 14px 0;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    border-color: #59B2E6;
}
.btn-login:hover,
.btn-login:focus {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #53A3CD;
    border-color: #53A3CD;
}
.forgot-password {
    text-decoration: underline;
    color: #888;
}
.forgot-password:hover,
.forgot-password:focus {
    text-decoration: underline;
    color: #666;
}

.btn-register {
    background-color: #1CB94E;
    outline: none;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 14px;
    height: auto;
    font-weight: normal;
    padding: 14px 0;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    border-color: #1CB94A;
}
.btn-register:hover,
.btn-register:focus {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #1CA347;
    border-color: #1CA347;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
 <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
 <link href="https://gitcdn.github.io/bootstrap-toggle/2.2.2/css/bootstrap-toggle.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/addon.css">
 <title>CC Targets</title>
</head>
<body>

<nav class="mb0 navbar navbar-static-top white-background navbar-logo pt20" role="navigation">
 <div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
    <div class="navbar-header">
     <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#mainNavbar">
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
     </button>

     <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><span class="secondary-color font-size-36">Super Signals</span></a>
    </div>     
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</nav>

<nav class="navbar navbar-static-top white-background navbar-items" role="navigation">
 <div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2 pl0">
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse nav-main" id="mainNavbar">
     <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li class="active"><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></span> Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign"></span> About</a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-list-alt"></span> Targets</a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></span> Contact</a></li>
     </ul>

     <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
      <?php if (!isset($_SESSION['name'])) { ?>
      <li><a href="login"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> Login</a></li>
      <?php } else { ?>
      <li class="dropdown">
       <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span><?php echo " " . $_SESSION['name'];?>
        <span class="caret"></span>
       </a>
       <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a href="overzicht">Overzicht</a></li>
        <li><a href="logout">Log uit</a></li>
       </ul>
      </li>

      <?php } ?>
     </ul>
    </div>     
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</nav>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://gitcdn.github.io/bootstrap-toggle/2.2.2/js/bootstrap-toggle.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/cookie.js"></script>
<script src="js/script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

This piece of code is where you broke nav:

```
.navbar-items {
    display: none;
}
```

Remove it and nav will work.

Answer (score 0):

> Remove css code 
>   .navbar-items {
>           display: none;
>       }

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Bree+Serif');
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway');

body{
 background: #f3f3f3;

}

.customfont{
    font-family: 'Bree Serif', serif; 
}

.bold{
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #999;
}

div.target{
 display: block;
 height: auto;
 border-radius: 6.666px;
 background: #ffffff;
}

.progress {
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    border-radius: 5px;

}

.progress-value {
    font-family: arial-black;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    color: black;
 
}

p.afstand {
    line-height: 50%;
}

a{
 /*color: #FFFFFF;*/
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}

/*a:hover{
 color: #FFFFFF;
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}*/

.coin-plus {
    color: #1be061;
}

.coin-dip {
    color: crimson;
}

.hover-coin-link:hover {
    color: #1be061;
}

.progress-complete {
    color: white;
}

.progress-bar {
    background: #1be061;
    width: 100%;
    padding:15px 0;
}

.arial-black {
    font-family: 'arial-black';
}

.font-weight-800 {
    font-weight: 800;
}

.small-usd {
    color: grey;
}

.secondary-color {
    color: #053d66;
}

.progress {
    height: 30px !important;
}

.grey-background {
    background: #f3f3f3;
}

.white-background {
    background: white !important;
}

.nav-main {
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

.nav-main a {
    color: #356e98
}

.toggle.btn[data-toggle='toggle'] {
    float: right !important;
    margin-left: 10px
}

@media (min-width: 1500px) {
  .container {
    width: 1075px;
  }
}
.navbar .navbar-toggle .icon-bar {
    background-color: black;
    
}

@media (max-width: 1300px) {
    .navbar-header {
        float: none;
    }
    .navbar-left,.navbar-right {
        float: none !important;
    }
    .navbar-toggle {
        display: block;
    }
    .navbar-collapse {
        border-top: 1px solid transparent;
        box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.1);
    }
    .navbar-fixed-top {
        top: 0;
        border-width: 0 0 1px;
    }
    .navbar-collapse.collapse {
        display: none!important;
    }
    .navbar-nav {
        float: none!important;
        margin-top: 7.5px;

        max-height: 300px;
        overflow-y: scroll!important;
    }
    .navbar-nav>li {
        float: none;
    }
    .navbar-nav>li>a {
        padding-top: 10px;
        padding-bottom: 10px;
    }
    .collapse.in{
        display:block !important;
    }
    .navbar-logo {
        padding-bottom: 20px;
    }
}


.panel-login {
    border-color: #ccc;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 2px 3px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 2px 3px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    box-shadow: 0px 2px 3px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}
.panel-login>.panel-heading {
    color: #00415d;
    background-color: #fff;
    border-color: #fff;
    text-align:center;
}
.panel-login>.panel-heading a{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #666;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 15px;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.1s linear;
    -moz-transition: all 0.1s linear;
    transition: all 0.1s linear;
}
.panel-login>.panel-heading a.active{
    color: #029f5b;
    font-size: 18px;
}
.panel-login>.panel-heading hr{
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    clear: both;
    border: 0;
    height: 1px;
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(left,rgba(0, 0, 0, 0),rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15),rgba(0, 0, 0, 0));
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(left,rgba(0,0,0,0),rgba(0,0,0,0.15),rgba(0,0,0,0));
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(left,rgba(0,0,0,0),rgba(0,0,0,0.15),rgba(0,0,0,0));
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(left,rgba(0,0,0,0),rgba(0,0,0,0.15),rgba(0,0,0,0));
}
.panel-login input[type="text"],.panel-login input[type="email"],.panel-login input[type="password"] {
    height: 45px;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    font-size: 16px;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.1s linear;
    -moz-transition: all 0.1s linear;
    transition: all 0.1s linear;
}
.panel-login input:hover,
.panel-login input:focus {
    outline:none;
    -webkit-box-shadow: none;
    -moz-box-shadow: none;
    box-shadow: none;
    border-color: #ccc;
}
.btn-login {
    background-color: #59B2E0;
    outline: none;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 14px;
    height: auto;
    font-weight: normal;
    padding: 14px 0;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    border-color: #59B2E6;
}
.btn-login:hover,
.btn-login:focus {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #53A3CD;
    border-color: #53A3CD;
}
.forgot-password {
    text-decoration: underline;
    color: #888;
}
.forgot-password:hover,
.forgot-password:focus {
    text-decoration: underline;
    color: #666;
}

.btn-register {
    background-color: #1CB94E;
    outline: none;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 14px;
    height: auto;
    font-weight: normal;
    padding: 14px 0;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    border-color: #1CB94A;
}
.btn-register:hover,
.btn-register:focus {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #1CA347;
    border-color: #1CA347;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
 <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
 <link href="https://gitcdn.github.io/bootstrap-toggle/2.2.2/css/bootstrap-toggle.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/addon.css">
 <title>CC Targets</title>
</head>
<body>

<nav class="mb0 navbar navbar-static-top white-background navbar-logo pt20" role="navigation">
 <div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
    <div class="navbar-header">
     <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#mainNavbar">
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
     </button>

     <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><span class="secondary-color font-size-36">Super Signals</span></a>
    </div>     
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</nav>

<nav class="navbar navbar-static-top white-background navbar-items" role="navigation">
 <div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2 pl0">
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse nav-main" id="mainNavbar">
     <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li class="active"><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></span> Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign"></span> About</a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-list-alt"></span> Targets</a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></span> Contact</a></li>
     </ul>

     <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
      <?php if (!isset($_SESSION['name'])) { ?>
      <li><a href="login"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> Login</a></li>
      <?php } else { ?>
      <li class="dropdown">
       <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span><?php echo " " . $_SESSION['name'];?>
        <span class="caret"></span>
       </a>
       <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a href="overzicht">Overzicht</a></li>
        <li><a href="logout">Log uit</a></li>
       </ul>
      </li>

      <?php } ?>
     </ul>
    </div>     
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</nav>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://gitcdn.github.io/bootstrap-toggle/2.2.2/js/bootstrap-toggle.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/cookie.js"></script>
<script src="js/script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```